# asp.net web api controller method taking special parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, query-string

I have an api that takes 2 parameters by querystring :

We call it like this :

```
mydomain/myapimethod?url=www.toto.com&caller=tata
```

We receive parameters like this :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("myapimethod")]    
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string url, [FromUri] string caller)
{
    //here url: www.toto.com and caller: tata
}
```

Everything is working well, the problem is when the url parameter is also composed of querystring with several parameters, for example :

```
mydomain/myapimethod?url=www.toto.com?parama=a&paramb=b&caller=tata
```

Then in my method :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("myapimethod")]    
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string url, [FromUri] string caller)
{
    //here url: www.toto.com?parama=a and caller: tata
    // my paramb is removed
    // what I would like to do is to obtain :
    // url: www.toto.com?parama=a&paramb and caller: tata
}
```

My url is generatated by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your url from

`mydomain/myapimethod?url=www.toto.com?parama=a&paramb=b&caller=tata`

to

`mydomain/myapimethod?url=www.toto.com&parama=a&paramb=b&caller=tata`

or encode question mark to %3F

```
mydomain/myapimethod?url=www.toto.com%3Fparama=a&paramb=b&caller=tata
```